# Can't download iOS app using in house at iOS 10.3 release version

Tags: ios, safari

I update the iOS to iOS 10.3 release version,

I try to download the in-house app through the safari,

but show the below error message(the log from device ).

```
  itunesstored(libsystem_network.dylib)[240] <Error>: nw_coretls_callback_handshake_message_block_invoke_3 tls_handshake_continue: [-9812]
  itunesstored(CFNetwork)[240] <Notice>:      NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
  itunesstored(CFNetwork)[240] <Error>: HTTP load failed (error code: -1202 [3:-9813])
  itunesstored(CFNetwork)[240] <Error>:      NSURLSessionTask finished with error - code: -1202
  itunesstored[240] <Notice>: LoadExternalDownloadManifestOperation: Request failed with error: <private>
  itunesstored[240] <Error>: Could not load download manifest with underlying error: <private>
```

I test the in house to install at the iOS 10.2.1. It is install correct.

But the iOS 10.3 will show the alert ( cannot connect to IP ).

Have anyone known what happened in my case?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out, it seems just trusting the certificate is no longer enough.  You need to go into General -> About (yes, About, what a great place) -> Certificate Trust Settings.  Then tick the switch next to your CA to trust it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kevin!! Why didn't you met me before.